# SplitterDistance changes as size of control changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, splitcontainer

I have a SplitContainer control on my form. It's docked to the form. And I set the `SplitterDistance` from code when the form loads.

This works fine except that the `SplitterDistance` changes when I resize the form. For example, when I make the form wider, the `SplitterDistances` seems to become larger so that it retains about the same percentage of width of the parent.

I don't want this. I want the distance between the splitter bar and the left of the control to stay the same as the window is resized. However, I don't want to set `IsSplitterFixed = true` because I still want to allow the user to change it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set [`FixedPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.fixedpanel?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property to the panel which you want to remain the same size when the container is resized. You can do it using designer, or using code:

```
this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Important note for screen scaling independence:  Setting the FixedPanel should be done in the Form_shown event.  If you set the SplitContainer FixedPanel in the form designer, the SplitterDistance that you set in the designer is applied literally, and not proportionally.  If you set it in the Form_shown, it is scaled appropriately for the desired fixed panel.